# It should work like a lottery, the computer thinks out a random number and you have to guess it, but it always writes that the number is too big

Tags: c#, if-statement

It should work like a lottery, the computer thinks out a random number and you have to guess it, but it always writes that the number is too big.

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Activation

```
namespace HelloSasha
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int number = rnd.Next(0, 100);
```

Randomizer

```
            Console.WriteLine("Write your number");
            string sUserNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            int iUserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sUserNumber);
```

User number

```
            bool x = true;
            while (x == true)
            {
                if (iUserNumber > number)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("So big");
                Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (iUserNumber < number)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("So small");
                Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                else if (iUserNumber == number)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("You win");
                Console.ReadLine();
                x = false;
```

All IF

```
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask for that number *within* the loop. Right now your user number is never updated

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Write your number");
string sUserNumber = Console.ReadLine();
int iUserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sUserNumber);
```

You're only calling these lines once.  So your program is stuck on the same number every time.  At the end of your loop, you need to get a new number from the user.